# How does a finite state machine perform division?

Tags: models, state-machine, fsm, computation

I am taking a course on models of computation and currently we are doing finite state machines. One my tasks is to draw out a FSM that performs division of 3; to simplify the model the machine only accepts numbers multiple of 3. I am not sure how this exactly works, especially since I imagine FSM putting out only single binary values. Could you guys give examples (division by 2 or 4) or hints on how to approach this?

Comment: Finite state machines have only binary output, so you can't possible output the division result. Are you sure you weren't asked do to create a machine which only accepts multiples of three?

Comment: "Create an FSM that outputs x/3, where x is the input.

The digits of the number, from left to right, will be fed to the FSM.You can assume the input will be a multiple of 3."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: FSM for dividing by 3]

This is what you need, I think (sorry about the bad picture). The 'E' represents epsilon/lambda/no-output. The label of the edges denotes 'input/output'. For each symbol read there is also a corresponding output which may be lambda (no output).

Comment: Sorry to come back to you so late. I dropped this class as it was taking up way to much time. Still, thank you very much.

Comment: What is the aproach to get the answer. I have a similar problem and want to get there by myself. But I need some hints... Thanks in advance.